# Passing multiple values through J Query and displaying in them in a div

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I’m attempting to pass multiple values through J Query and displaying in a div. The code below works fine for single values.

```
<script type="text/jscript">
function get1() {
    $.post('viewexisting.php', { 
            Status: reportform.Status.value, 
            Date1: reportform.Date1.value, 
            Date2: reportform.Date2.value
        },
        function (output) {
            $('#info').html(output).show();
        });
}
</script>

<form name="reportform">
<?php
{
    $box1 = array();
    $result1 = "SELECT Status FROM CT:Status";
    $rs1 = odbc_exec($conn1,$result1);

    while($row = odbc_fetch_array($rs1)) {
        $box1[] = $row;
    }
}

$Status = '<select name="Status" multiple="multiple size="7">';
$Status .= '<option selected="selected">---< All Statuses >---</option>';

if (!empty($box1)) {
    foreach ($box1 as $k => $v) {
        $Status .= '<option value="'.$v['Status'].'">'.$v['Status'].'</option>';
    }
}
$Status .= '</select>';
echo $Status; 
?>

Date Range: <br>From <input name="Date1" id="Date1" type="text"><br>
To <input name="Date2" id="Date2" type="text">
<input type="button" value="Apply Date Range" onclick="get1();" style="width: 146px">

</form>
<div id="info"></div>
```

But when I try to put [] behind Status in the select name and in the script, the button stops working. select name="Status[]" does work if I'm using a form with a post method to another page though. I would like to make it work with the javascript. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Tip: `reportform.Status.value` - there is a way to do this with JQuery, which might work here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to pass multiple values from the select box then you need to set a name with brackets to define it as an array, so you should use "Status[]" as you mentioned but the line to retrieve the value in your `get1()` function will no longer work since the name of the element has changed. I noticed you are sending all your inputs through post and that you're using jQuery so you might as well do this:

```
function get1() {
    $.post('viewexisting.php', 
           $('form[name="reportform"]').serialize(), 
           function (output) {
               $('#info').html(output).show();
           });
}
```

Comment: I’m not sure how to retrieve it on the next page. I was using, 
    $Status = addslashes($_POST['Status']);
    $Date1 = addslashes($_POST['Date1']);
    $Date2 = addslashes($_POST['Date2']);
And tried,
    $Status = unserialize($_POST['form']);
    $Status = unserialize($_POST['reportForm']);
Bu neither worked…

Comment: you should be able to access them normally, ex: $_POST['Status'], I updated my answer because I realized I had a capital "F" in the form selector, while in your markup it's all lowercase, make sure it is consistent in your code

Comment: That did it! Needed a $Status = implode(", ", $_POST['Status']); on the next page, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `[]` as your post names, it becomes an array. You need to iterate the array... in PHP: `foreach($array as $item)`; in jQuery, you can use `$.each(array, function(key, value) { })`